# Logging to File in Python Producing API Request/Data Unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I've recently configured a logger in python w/ the logging module. However, even without any debug statements or references to the logging function, it appears to be outputting request/api debug information to the log file w/o even being referenced every time I run my code.

This is how it's configured

```py
def configureFile():
    logging.basicConfig(filename=f"..\..\logs\{cleanDate(str(datetime.now()))}.txt",
                        filemode='a',
                        format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                        level=logging.DEBUG)
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.propagate = False
```

& this is the output it's producing

```
00:11:33,17 ccxt.base.exchange DEBUG 516 GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo, Request: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'} None
00:11:33,23 urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG 824 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.binance.com
00:11:33,368 urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG 396 https://api.binance.com:443 "GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo HTTP/1.1" 200 None
00:11:33,382 ccxt.base.exchange DEBUG 552 GET https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo, Response: 200 {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Thu, 12 Mar 2020 07:11:31 GMT', 'Server': 'nginx', 'X-MBX-UUID': 'c3f53d4a-2f6c-4c56-80b1-7b4ba8986dbb', 'X-MBX-USED-WEIGHT': '1', 'X-MBX-USED-WEIGHT-1M': '1', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'", 'X-Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self'", 'X-WebKit-CSP': "default-src 'self'", 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '0', 'X-Cache': 'Miss from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Thank you so much

Comment: Try setting the logging level to error or warning.

Comment: @SubhashR Fixed it like a charm.. thank you so much

Comment: The reason is that a module you are importing is writing logs. Most notably the `requests` module has logging inbuilt that will start showing logs once a logger is configured.